# Posting comments on images Instagram from IPhone app

Tags: iphone, oauth, instagram

I have integrated Instagram in my app using Instagram api. I want to post comment on image from app. How can I post comments using Instagram api
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN' \
-F 'text=This+is+my+comment' \
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments
```

Please Refer http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/comments/

Comment: did you use a valid access token?